# Python Azure SDK Equivalent of CloudConfigurationManager

Tags: python, azure, configuration, sdk

Is there a Python equivalent of:
Microsoft.Azure.CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting

Currently I locate the ServiceConfiguration.cscfg file, and parse it!!

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed the [source codes](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python) & [api documents](http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#) of Azure SDK for Python, I didn't find any information about the feature in Python which be equivalent of `Microsoft.Azure.CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting` in C#.

Meanwhile, it seems that Azure Python SDK only support for reading the `.cscfg` file to create a Cloud Service deployment via service management client as the code `configuration = base64.b64encode(open(file_path, 'rb').read('path_to_.cscfg_file'))` which from [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/f8dc98625404b75e5d6365ad30c04abc90ee751a/doc/servicemanagement.rst).

So seems that parsing the `.cscfg` file is the only way to get the properties of cloud service.